# Getting a certain decimal length from a model

Tags: c#, model

I am working on creating a model where I want all of the decimal values to end up being 2 decimal places (currency). This is what I was thinking, but obviously doesn't work.

```
public class Fees
{
    public decimal permitFee { set; get { return Math.Round(permitFee, 2); } }
    public decimal planReviewFee { set; get { return Math.Round(planReviewFee, 2); } }
    public decimal surchargeFee { set; get { return Math.Round(surchargeFee, 2); } }
    public decimal totalFee { get { return permitFee + planReviewFee + surchargeFee; } }
}
```

How should I setup my object so I get the correct outputted value?

Comment: will you use them for some calculations, or just will be shown to the user?

Comment: If you have a strict requirement to limit the currency values to two decimal places, you'll want to store them as integers that end at the last decimal place you want to keep. (For example $100.42 would be stored as 10042 in an integer variable.) Otherwise, storage of fractional values will always be inaccurately stored because of conversion of base 10 fractions.

Comment: Can the set accessor be blank if the get isn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you can use a property like that (returning itself). Try using an underlying variable for the property and see if that fixes your problem.

[Stack overflow error in C# set/get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398219/stack-overflow-error-in-c-sharp-set-get)

Answer (score 1):

See my comment above and consider storing the values as integers

```
public class Fees {  

private int permit;  
private int planReview;  
private int surcharge;  
public decimal permitFee { set { permit = (int) (value * 100); }; 
                           get { return permit / 100; } }  
public decimal planReviewFee { set { planReview = (int) (value * 100); } 
                               get { return planReview / 100; } }
public decimal surchargeFee { set { surcharge = (int) (value * 100); } 
                              get { return surcharge / 100; } }
public decimal totalFee { get { return permitFee + planReviewFee + surchargeFee; } }  }  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing taking @tom_yes_tom's suggestion.

```
public class Fees
{
    private decimal permit;
    private decimal planReview;
    private decimal surcharge;

    public decimal permitFee
    {
        set { permit = Math.Round(value, 2); }
        get { return permit; }
    }
    public decimal planReviewFee 
    {
        set { planReview = Math.Round(value, 2); }
        get { return planReview; } 
    }
    public decimal surchargeFee 
    {
        set { surcharge = Math.Round(value, 2); }
        get { return surcharge; } 
    }
    public decimal totalFee 
    { 
        get { return permitFee + planReviewFee + surchargeFee; } 
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you did exactly what I suggested doing. =)